# Qt installer framework built installation package crashing after start

Tags: macos, qt, build, qt-installer

I'm using Qt installer framework 1.4. Works fine for Windows, but I have a problem on Mac OSX.

As stated in the [manual](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtifw-1.3/ifw-tutorial.html), I switched to the tutorial directory and ran this command

```
../../bin/binarycreator -c config\config.xml -p packages YourInstaller
```

The installer was built with no problem, but after running it, I get an error

> YourInstaller quit unexpectedly

I tried it in 10.8.2 and 10.7.4 versions of Mac OSX. Same result.

Crash report:

```
Process:         YourInstaller [317]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/YourInstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/YourInstaller
Identifier:      com.yourcompany.installerbase
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [113]

Date/Time:       2013-09-25 19:01:17.833 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          120529 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  37 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   3
Anonymous UUID:                      BD392C87-1080-4663-B36C-20F3CF6EA085

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[317]: garbage collection is OFF
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81f73ce2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff832ce7d2 pthread_kill + 95
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff832bfa7a abort + 143
3   com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x0000000100ada3b5 qt_message_output(QtMsgType, char const*) + 149
4   com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x0000000100ada56d _ZL10qt_message9QtMsgTypePKcP13__va_list_tag + 381
5   com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x0000000100ada78d qFatal(char const*, ...) + 141
6   com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x000000010044efca qt_init(QApplicationPrivate*, int) + 2218
7   com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x00000001004bda4b QApplicationPrivate::construct() + 187
8   com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x00000001004be83d QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) + 95
9   com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x000000010000e8bf MyApplication::MyApplication(int&, char**) + 25
10  com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x0000000100005dda main + 5594
11  com.yourcompany.installerbase   0x00000001000047d4 start + 52
```

Comment: Try to start the actual installer binary (inside the .app directory) from command line, the backtrace suggests there's an error message (printed via qFatal))

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got an error "qt_menu.nib could not be loaded" and fixed it.

Comment: How did you fix it, out of the curiosity? Also, quote us next time like "@Foo", otherwise, it is likely we will not read it anymore. There are so many people to help, so you need to "ring" the people trying to help. :)

Comment: I just added "qt_menu.nib" file to "Contents/Resources" directory of .app bundle